# Bit Selection in C

Tags: c, binary

I am trying to select bits [0:2] and bits [6:8] of the bit-string 1010000000001. Bits [0:2] are 001 and bits [6:8] are 000. I tried to select these bits with:

```
int instr = 0x1401;
int src2 = (instr & 0x0006); //get bits [2:0]
int src1 = (instr & 0x01C0) >> 6; //get bits [6:8]

printf("%04x, %04x",src2, src1);
```

However I am getting that src1 and src2 are both 0000. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing incorrectly so I can select bits [0:2] and [6:8]?

Comment: I am trying to select the bits [0:2] and [6:8]

Comment: 1 + 2 + 4 = 7. So use `0x7` to get the three least significant bits, not `0x6`.

Comment: Bit 0 has value 1, not 0, so your mask of 6 is off-by-1.

Comment: `0x7` is correct and the `src1` is actually 000 - change your input to `11011011011` or something like that to make it easy to see

Comment: The constants for getting the value for `src1` might be easier to determine and the code easier to read if you `>> 6` shift first and only then mask the lowest three bits by `&7`.

Comment: `uint32_t instr; ... uint32_t bitfield = (instr >> start_of_bitfield) & ((UINT32_C(1) << width_of_bitfield) - 1);` (width most be < 32!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned instr = 0x1401;
    unsigned src2 = instr & 0x0007;        //  7 in hex == 0000 0000 0111 in binary
    unsigned src1 = (instr & 0x01C) >> 6;  // 1C in hex == 0001 1100 0000 in binary

    printf("%04x, %04x", src2, src1);
}
```

It masks out the desired bits in `instr` and shifts them by the correct offset. Also, when doing bit manipulation, unsigned types are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to just write a function to calculate any arbitrary bit slice (here using `1` rather than `0` as the least significant bit):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int bit_select(int num, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    assert(end >= start);

    const int mask = (1 << (end-start+1)) - 1;
    const int shift = start - 1;

    return (num & (mask << shift)) >> shift;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Bits 1...3 of 01100101: %d\n", bit_select(0x65, 1, 3));
    printf("Bits 3...3 of 01100101: %d\n", bit_select(0x65, 3, 3));
    printf("Bits 4...4 of 01100101: %d\n", bit_select(0x65, 4, 4));
    printf("Bits 3...7 of 01100101: %d\n", bit_select(0x65, 3, 7));

    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./bitselect
Bits 1...3 of 01100101: 5
Bits 3...3 of 01100101: 1
Bits 4...4 of 01100101: 0
Bits 3...7 of 01100101: 25
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: The use of `assert()` and `pow()` seems to make it somewhat inefficient.

Comment: Efficiency of `assert()` is irrelevant, since it's a no-op in release build. Using `pow()` is more efficient than manually calculating, writing out, and debugging a thousand individually specified masks, and then writing a Stack Overflow question about the problems you're having with them.

Comment: Why not use `mask = (1 << (end-start+1)) - 1` instead of `pow()`? And why not just return `(num >> shift) & mask`? But then, this is for educational purposes, not for production use, so who cares about efficiency.

Comment: @ndim: Fair play on the first point, that's definitely worth amending, answer updated. Second is also fair, but I've left the answer as it is, on the grounds that I think it makes it a little clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see if you get the result from 0x1401 & 0x0006 you get 0 and you get the same from 0x1401 & 0x01c0. The bit shift you do on src1 is just 0 shift right 6 bits which is still 0.

Comment: Ah, ok. So how would I get the first three bits 001?

Comment: For bits [0:3] that would be 0x000f, for [0:2] that would be 0x0007, for [6:8] that would be 0x01c0

Answer (score 0):

Because you provided a wrong mask.

To make life easier if you are using gcc, just provide binary literal rather than hex version so that you can see what you are masking off without pain:

```
unsigned src2 = instr & 0b111;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int instr = 0x1401;
//results in instr containing (ignoring endian)
//0x00001401
//or in binary
//0b0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100 0000 0001

//extracting bits 2:0 is normally done by:
int src2 = instr & 0x00000007;

//extracting bits 8:6 is normally done by:
int src1 = (instr & 0x000001C0) >> 6;

//note that if bit 31 is to be extracted,
//the bit shifting will not work
//due to sign propagation of a negative number
```